# compare 2 files based on 2 fields and give unmatched records using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have 2 csv files with same format.

File 1:

```
account, desc, user, date
123, savings, 777, 22092014
234, current, 773, 22092014
456, savings, 772, 22092014
```

File 2:

```
account, desc, user, date
123, savings, 778, 22092014
765, savings, 779, 22092014
```

Keys from the files are 1st and 3rd fields from both the files. output should be only the record with modified key from both the files.user for account "123" is changed in second file.

We need only this record to be part of output file

```
123, savings, 778, 22092014
```

Comment: You say the key changes. Must all the other fields be the same?

Comment: we dont need to worry about fields other than 1 & 3 though they should b part of output file

Comment: Can account change or just the user? If account can change, how can you tell if both account and user changed?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {user[$1]=$3; next} $1 in user && user[$1] != $3' file1 file2
```

```
123, savings, 778, 22092014
```

Comment: Maybe you could give some explanation on how your answer works. It would allow other with a different use case to adapt your answer to their cases...